# 500 Error using value in HTML and calling JSP/Java

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp

Hey in the following code I have some error but don't know what it's causing. I made a drop down menu to select an option in the HTML. The content and the value of the option of the select block should be different. And currently I'm getting a 500 error .

When the content and the value is just "resultset.getInt(4)" the program works and the operation to the database is execute.

That's my HTML file:

```
<%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.Context"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Allocation Paket</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="paket_update.jsp" method="post">
        <table border="0">
        <%ResultSet resultset =null;
          ResultSet resultset1 =null;%>
                <%
                Context initContext = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myoracle");
                try(Connection con= ds.getConnection()){
                    con.setAutoCommit(false);

                    Statement statement = con.createStatement() ;
                    Statement statement1 = con.createStatement() ;

                    resultset =statement.executeQuery("SELECT m.vorname, m.nachname, m.angestelltennummer, b.svnr FROM bote b JOIN mitarbeiter m ON m.svnr = b.svnr") ;
                    resultset1 =statement1.executeQuery("SELECT paketnummer FROM paket") ;

                %>
                <td>Bote:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="bote">
                    <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
                    <option value="<% resultset.getInt(4);%>"><%= resultset.getString(1)+", "+resultset.getString(2)+", " + resultset.getInt(3) %></option>

                     <% } %>                
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>Paket:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="paket">
                    <%  while(resultset1.next()){ %>
                    <option ><%= resultset1.getInt(1) %></option>
                     <% } %>                
                    </select>
                </td>
                                <%
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                         out.println("wrong entry"+e);
                    }           
                %>


        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Insert"/>   
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="index.html">Zur Startseite</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

That's my jsp file (update paket):

```
<%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.Context"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Update Paket</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myoracle");
    String s="Der Bote wurde erfolgreich zugewiesen!";
    try(Connection con= ds.getConnection()){
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        String query = "UPDATE paket SET BOTE = ? WHERE PAKETNUMMER=?";

        try(PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)){
            int svnr = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("bote"));
            int paketnummer =  Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("paket"));

            stmt.setInt(1,svnr);
            stmt.setInt(2,paketnummer);

            stmt.execute();

            con.commit();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            out.println("Fehler: " + ex.getMessage() + " (" + ex.getSQLState() + ')');
            s="Der Bote wurde nicht zugewiesen";
            try {
                con.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                out.println("Rollback nicht erfolgreich! Fehler: " + ignore.getMessage() + " ("
                        + ignore.getSQLState() + ')');
            }
        }

    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        out.println("Fehler: " + ex.getMessage() + " (" + ex.getSQLState() + ')');
    }
    out.println(s);
    %>
        <br>
    <a href="index.html">Zur Startseite</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me^^

Comment: 1) The HTML code (which in fact also a JSP is...) is incomplete, where is the second form field (passed as second parameter to the form action) "paket"? 2) Is the "jsp file" the one named "paket_update.jsp"? 3) Where is variable "s" defined in the JSP? This can't work as it is now. (Bitte vollständige Code-Beispiele angeben, sonst schaut sich das niemand an).

Comment: ok thx updated the code and is now it's the whole file

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please can you provide more details about the HTTP 500 error, maybe also a stacktrace from the app server log, which could give a hint about the error location? PS I've might have found the issue, and I created a answer, please check if that's the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this line is wrong, because of a missing `=` character at the beginning of
`"<% resultset.getInt(4);%>"`:

```
<option value="<% resultset.getInt(4);%>"><%= resultset.getString(1)+", "+resultset.getString(2)+", " + resultset.getInt(3) %></option>
```

Because of that nothing is written to `out`, and all generated `option` tags have `value=""`. Should be, in my opinion:

```
<option value="<%= resultset.getInt(4);%>"><%= resultset.getString(1)+", "+resultset.getString(2)+", " + resultset.getInt(3) %></option>
```